# Python pip install package not overwrite previous deployed data files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have a python package with below setup file

```
setup(...
    data_files=[('//etc/blahDir', ['blahFile', ...
```

when install this package via pip, the contained blahFile not overwrite the existing one under the /etc/blahDir. I guess this is due to the existing one has a newer timestamp than the included one.

So is there any command in pip or config in setup.py can force to update this file? Or is there some way I can clean up those deployed data_files?

Thanks!

Comment: Even when you use ``pip install -U``?